# How can I install gem libv8 in Mac OS Big Sur 11.0?

Tags: rubygems, macos-big-sur, libv8

When I try to install the libv8 gem version 7.3.492.27.1 with command

```
gem install libv8 -v '7.3.492.27.1'
```

it fails with

```
unable to fetch v8 source
```

How can I install libv8 in Mac OS Big Sur 11.0?

Answer (score 2):

You can install the binary build of the gem provided by [Loic Nageleisen](https://github.com/lloeki)

https://github.com/rubyjs/libv8/issues/305

Search in there the file

```
 https://www.dropbox.com/s/wuwuqhaqcate8k5/libv8-8.4.255.0-x86_64-darwin-20.gem?dl=0
```

download and install with

```
gem install path-to-gem-file/libv8-8.4.255.0-x86_64-darwin-20.gem
```

Then you already have libv8 working in Mac OS Big Sur 11.0

In your Gemfile.lock there should be

```
GEM
  specs
    ...
    libv8 (7.3.492.27.1-x86_64-darwin-20)
    ...

PLATFORMS
  ...
  x86_64-darwin-20
  ....
```